# Маршрутизация react-yandex-map выдает ошибку 403

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь настроить маршруты в react-yandex-map, выдает 403 ошибку с RouteButton, а если выбираю маршруты с открытой панелью разработчика, выдает то 401, то 403 ошибку (скрины ниже); код предельно простой, ошибок нет, есть варианты?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { YMaps, Map, GeoObject, Placemark, Polyline, RouteButton} from 'react-yandex-maps';

class App extends React.Component {
  
  render () {
    
    return  <YMaps >
              <Map className="map" defaultState={{ center: [55.75, 37.57], zoom: 15 }} >
                <RouteButton options={{ float: 'right' }} />
              </Map>
            </YMaps>
  }
}
export default App;
```

[image: ошибки]

Comment: Очевидно вы используете API без ключа или с невалидным ключом. Проверьте, что всё делаете правильно по документации.

Comment: У меня немного опыта, но думаю, что документация именно для реакта написано не очень подробно. А может быть проблемы со мной.

Answer (score 1):

Аутентифицироваться надо, вероятно -- яндекс хочет знать, кто вы